# Как получить из textarea value и вывести в файл

Tags: php

Хочу сделать админку на сайт, который ищет по бд, не суть.
Нужно чтобы он получал из формы на сайте (textarea) данные, например:
login:password
login2:password2 (с новой строки каждый)
[image: фото]

Помогите пожалуйста, или тыкните пальцем в функцию

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, что-то вроде этого должно Вам помочь:

```
<?php
$textarea_data = $_POST['textarea_name'] ?? '';

if ( !empty( $textarea_data ) ) {
   $textarea_data = explode( "\n", $textarea_data );
   $total_array = [];
   foreach ( $textarea_data as $line ) {
     list( $key, $value ) = explode( ':', $line, 2 );
     $total_array[ $key ] = $value;
   }
}
```

Получится что-то вроде массива:

```
[
  "login" => "pass",
  "login2" => "pass2",
]
```

Только Вам необходимо отправлять данные на сервер через форму или Ajax-запрос